# Checking to see if li values are the same

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

Code:

```
$('#friends_list ul li').click(function () {
    var name = $(this).attr('value');
    var parentlist = $('#chat_opened ul');
    var overflow = parentlist.children('li').length;
    var allowed = 5;
    var childC = parentlist.children('li').attr('value');
    if (overflow <= allowed && childC != name) {
        parentlist.append('<li value="' + name + '">' + name + ' Chat</li>');
    } else if (overflow > allowed) {
        $('#inner_overflow ul').append('<li value="' + name + '">' + name + ' Chat</li>');
    }
```

Within the line of my if statement I am trying to compare if two variables are true then do the following. So basically if `overflow` is less than or equal to the allowed number  as well as `childC` does not equal the `name` append to the parentlist

the else if is going to be the same after i figure out how to compare the two li values.

EX:

```
<ul>
 <li value="usersname">Username</li>
<ul>
<ul> 
  <li value="usersname">Username</li>//no more than two in this unordered list
</ul>
```

So when the user clicks the first `ul li` it will append another `li` to the second `ul` but not twice. as of now it will append 100s of the same `li` so I need to figure out how to make it so the second ul will not duplicate any of the same `li`s with the same value.

Comment: A `LI` element does'nt have a value ?

Comment: Your HTML code isn't valid.

Comment: `value` is no valid attribute on `<li>` elements.

Comment: Value can still be used so users don't see this item, title will be shown on hover. So I am using the value attribute. It is still accepted in all modern browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without going into all of the changes that you COULD make to your code, to accomplish what you are asking with what you have, you could simply be to check for the number of `<li>`'s in the target list that have that value that you are ready to add:

```
var name = $(this).attr('value');
var parentlist = $('#chat_opened ul');
var overflow = parentlist.children('li').length;
var allowed = 5;
var duplicates = parentlist.find('li[value="' + name + '"]');

if (overflow <= allowed && duplicates.length < 1) {
    . . .
```

That would check to see if there were any `<li>`'s that already existed with that value.  If there aren't (i.e., `length < 1`), then you are safe to add the value.

Comment: upvote for not stating of value not a valid li attribute when in fact it is. now is `li[value="blah"]` cross compatible? I don't remember what those are called.

Comment: I used your method and honestly it is the best and most straight forward to be honest. I am going to use this, just please answer if it is cross browser compatible. Thank you

Comment: Well, yes and no . . . the general `li[foo="bar"]` approach is cross-browser compatible, but this is where what some of the other people were saying comes into play.  IE doesn't like it when you try to access an attribute that is defined for other elements (like `value`) as a custom attribute for an element where it hasn't been defined.  If you were to use `val`, for example, it would work fine everywhere, but, because `value` is a standard attribute in other elements, it won't work in IE.

Comment: As for "not stating of value not a valid li attribute", I try not to make assumptions about the constraints that people are working under when answering questions . . . I had to support IE5.5 as part of my requirements for a project a few years back and the replies of "Why are you trying to support IE5.5?" when I asked for help got pretty old, pretty fast.   ;)

Comment: Very true on things getting old here. Especially people asking, "Why aren't you doing this server side" well because the constraints of the code needs to be client side lol :D Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you use HTML 4.01 you can do this:

```
<ol>
  <li value="username">User Name</li>
  ...
</ol>
```

But notice that [this is deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/lists.html#h-10.2).

```
$('#friends_list ul li').click(function () {
  var name = $(this).attr('value');
  var parentlist = $('#chat_opened ul');
  var overflow =0;
 //need to add these lines
  $('#friends_list ul li').each(function(i)
  {
   if($(this).attr('value')==name)
          overflow++;
   });
   var allowed = 5;
   var childC = parentlist.children('li').attr('value');
   if (overflow <= allowed && childC != name) {
   parentlist.append('<li value="' + name + '">' + name + ' Chat</li>');
  } else if (overflow > allowed) {
    $('#inner_overflow ul').append('<li value="' + name + '">' + name + ' Chat</li>');
 }
```

Comment: LI value is no longer deprecated in HTML5, and we can still use deprecated elements/attributes, just need to be weary of these. As I stated above I won't use the each function just because of the overload it has in its library in jQuery, I'd rather use the for loop. I will look more into your code and see what I can do with it.

Answer (score -1):

The `value` attributes is not valid on li element, but if you really want to use value on each li than you can use it with html-5 `data-` atribute like:

*Html*

```
<ul id='first'>
 <li data-value="usersname">Username</li>
<ul>
<ul id='second'> 
  <li data-value="usersname">Username</li>//no more than two in this unordered list
</ul>
```

*JS*

```
  $("#first > li").click(function(){
    var self = this;
    var present = false;
    $.each($("#second > li"), function(i,v){
       if($(v).data("value") ==  $(self).data("value")){
         present = true;
         return true;
       }
    });
    if(!present) {
     $("#second").append(self);
    }
    else
    {
      //item with same value already present in the secont ul list
    }
  });
```

Comment: I won't use the jQuery each I will only use the for loop. Also like stated above value is still accepted http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_li_value.asp#gsc.tab=0 and I know this for certain so I don't need to use the data preset